# Directory tree in a Resource without extraction…

Tags: c#, resources, geckofx

i am looking for a way to store a complete directory including sub directories in an application's resource and not have to extract it to use it.

Details:

- We would like to use [GeckoFx](http://geckofx.org/) (Gecko as C# Component) in one of our applications.
- GeckoFX needs the XUL-Runner and needs to find it's folder structure
- We have some other data which I would not prefer to extracted to the customer's pc; At least not onto something persistent like a hdd...

Getting the complete directory into the resources is not that kind of a big deal. Compress to one file and done.

But not writing it to the disk to use it is something else.

I have a strong dislike against temp folders and such things. Would anything like a RAM drive be possible? Some part of the RAM beeing mounted? Does something like this even exist as a lib, or would this only be possible by a device driver?

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Corelgott

Comment: This one looks really promissing...

http://dokan-dev.net/en/
http://code.google.com/p/dokan/

This would solve the problem entirely. Only drawback is the lib is not yet capable of mounting into a NTFS-Folder. It only supports mounting to driveletters. I'll try to implement this - If anything changes, i'll report back...

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeckoMulti, it will save you a lot of time, it has already got done what you are trying to implemented.